# Upgrade PHP 5.6 to 7.0?

Tags: php

i wonder if they is an option to upgrade php version 5.6 to 7.0
Ive seen some tips with information that i need to add new repository with php7.0, but its still not working for me.
If any one has checked options that work for him please share

Comment: You need to compile it yourself. https://www.symfony.fi/entry/install-php-7-on-raspbian-raspberry-pi

Comment: Do i need remove php 5.6 before install php7 ? or something else?

Comment: Ok i did everything from link that you send me and when i write in console "php -v" it gives me "PHP 7.0.7-3~bpo8+1" but when i open my phpinfo file with "<?php phpinfo(); ?> it show still "PHP Version 5.6.22-0+deb8u1".

Please help me to fix it.

Comment: ok i solved it with command:
"sudo a2dismod php5 ; sudo a2enmod php7.0 ; sudo service apache2 restart"
Now its version 7.0 but i cant access phpmyadmin